# apt-get command can't finish install

Tags: apt

I'm new on ubuntu and when I try to install MaxEnt 3.4.0 with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install maxent 3.4.0
```

It shows me this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libassa3.4-0-dev' for regex '3.4.0'
Note, selecting 'libavc1394-0' for regex '3.4.0'
E: Unable to locate package maxet
```

what should I do to fix it?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Maxent/VNluqUhv7NQ

Answer (score 2):

Reread `man apt-get`. Your command does not request the installation of `MaxEnt 3.4.0`", it requests the installation of two packages: `MaxEnt` and `3.4.0` (thus `regex '3.4.0'`).

I can find no hint of `MaxEnt`, `maxent`, `maxet` in the Xenial repositories - are sure it's available for Ubuntu?

Comment: i've heard that pepole are working with it in university on ubuntu! so gave it a chance to see if it works on this amazing OS or not.

Answer (score 0):

Maxent is not available in any of the Ubuntu repositories, so unless you add a repository that provides a Maxent package to download and manage via apt, you are not going to be able to install it using `apt-get`. From reading online, Maxent appears to be a Java application that doesn't provide any repositories; you might have to download the Maxent .jar and run it using the `java -jar` CLI tool.

Comment: thank you for guiding me, but the same error for each package: sudo apt-get install gcj-5-jre-headless
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gcj-5-jre-headless

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna have do to things the manual way, since Maxent isn't available for Ubuntu (never heard of it personally). However I found the github page for it. So go ahead and pipe in:

`gitclone https://github.com/lzhang10/maxent.git`

in your terminal after selecting a folder to clone the .git repository to.

Then, as the git repository indicates, follow the directions in the INSTALL file. It should be as simple as giving a `./config` , `make` then `sudo make install` executed from within your build folder.

Comment: Thank you for searching and helping me. as I said I'm new on ubuntu (just installed a new huge world on my laptop about 72 hours ago!) and I can not understand what your link is trying to tell me! (don know anything about ./configure! and other linuxic(I invented this one!) sentences) but thank you. I'm a learn loving person and I will find out a way to fix this issue with your link. thanks a lot. :)